# php get json string key and value

Tags: php, json

In php how get values of activity_id_0 and student_phone_0 and so on.
My json string is like

```
array(
    'json_text' => '{
    "student_activity":{"activity_id_0":"1","student_id_0":"1","charges_0":"123"},
    "student_contact_info":{"student_phone_0":"7867857986","student_id_0":"1","student_email_0":""}
    }'
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: i have tried json_decode but its giving me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode this json as array and get it by keys:

```
$a = array(
    'json_text' => '{
    "student_activity":{"activity_id_0":"1","student_id_0":"1","charges_0":"123"},
    "student_contact_info":{"student_phone_0":"7867857986","student_id_0":"1","student_email_0":""}
    }'
);
$json = json_decode($a['json_text'],true);
$activity_id_0 = $json["student_activity"]["activity_id_0"];
$student_phone_0 = $json["student_contact_info"]["student_phone_0"];
echo $activity_id_0,' ',$student_phone_0; //1 7867857986
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode()`:

```
$arr = array(
    'json_text' => '{
        "student_activity":{"activity_id_0":"1","student_id_0":"1","charges_0":"123"},
        "student_contact_info":{"student_phone_0":"7867857986","student_id_0":"1","student_email_0":""}
    }'
);

var_dump(json_decode($arr['json_text'])->student_contact_info->student_phone_0);
```

More info in the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to convert json object into an array, try below code

```
$info = array(
        'json_text' => '{
        "student_activity":{"activity_id_0":"1","student_id_0":"1","charges_0":"123"},
        "student_contact_info":{"student_phone_0":"7867857986","student_id_0":"1","student_email_0":""}
        }'
    );

    // here we can convert json object into an array
    $arrayInfo = json_decode($info['json_text'], true);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrayInfo['student_activity']);
    print_r($arrayInfo['student_contact_info']);
```

I think it will helpful for you.. :-)